# What is the significance of seeing Lord Vishnu, Lakshmi and Shiva together in a dream?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, lakshmi, dream

I had dream and saw Lord Vishnu, Mata Lakshmi, and Lord Shiva in my dream. I don't remember few things about that dream(don't know why) but Here is what I saw.. It was dream in which they were giving me chance to get moksha. Either Lord Vishnu or Lord Shiva (don't remember who exactly) told me that what should I do to get moksha. It was kind of test to attain moksha.

He ( either Vishnu or Shiva) told me that you have to walk on a path and reach to Lord Shiva in order to attain moksha. Path was few feets above ground and it was very narrow, means one has to balance himself to walk on that narrow path. In other words it was low hight wall on which we have to walk in order to reach Shiva. I wasn't alone. There were some Rishis also there who also trying to walk on path (like me) to reach Shiva so they can get moksha.

We all started to walk on that path, Path was not long. It was like circle. I could clearly see starting and ending of that path. At the end of path Lord Shiva was sitting and he was in dhyana. On around 25% ahead of starting point Lord Vishnu and Mata Lakshmi was sitting. Lord Vishnu was organizer of that test and was judging us. I could see all three sitting there. Vishnu and Mata Lakshami was sitting and watching us all walking on that path but Lord Shiva was in dhyana.

So we started walking on it. After little time one rishi lost his balance on that path and had his feets on ground (from 3 to 4 feet walls he fell on ground on his feet). But he didn't climb up that wall again but instead started to walk on ground instead in order to reach Shiva. By seeing this he(either Vishnu or Shiva) told him that it's not fair, walking on ground won't help, you have to get up on that narrow path and then start walking. Lord gave warning to that rishi in one line and in that line He used name Lakshman. He said something like "Lakshman chaal (don't remember rest)". So that rishi climbed up again and started to walk again.

There we get to know about rule that whoever lost balance on that path and fell down he will loose his chance of reaching to Shiva. One by one every Rishi started to fall. Later I also fell down, but I feeled it wasn't my fault that I fell down, I had confidence that If I get another chance then I can really complete that path. So I asked Lord Vishnu to give me another chance and He agreed.

I again started to walk on that path from starting point. This time I was alone. I had confident that I can do this but also little afraid. I traveled more than 50% path. But later I saw a shortcut and decided to use that instead. But I thought to ask from Vishnu whether I should follow this shortcut or not, Vishnu reply was no(as I remember but not sure). Little later Mata lakshmi said something to me(don't remember), May be she said not do this. Means don't walk any more on this path, you don't need to. But I was so determined to reach to Lord Shiva so that I can get moksha. So I replied to Mata Lakshmi something like *Don't interfear, let me do this*" By hearing this reply Mata Lakshmi got upset and set down with Lord Vishnu. She felt bad with my reply but she wasn't angry on me. She was just upset. But soon I fell down again. And lost my second chance of walking on that path.

I again asked from Vishnu that I wanna try again but Lord Vishnu said I want to  rest now. I felt like Lord Vishnu gave me enough time and He wanna take break. I understand that I agreed with Lord Vishnu's decision and dream got over.

For me, this dream was very confusing, because I am devote Of Lord Vishnu and Mata Lakshmi, not devotee of Lord Shiva. So I am so confused that why I need to reach to Lord Shiva to get moksha in my dream?

I do fasts of Lord Vishnu, Mata Lakshmi (Mata's fasts started nearly one month ago) fasts and Lord Hanuma. I asked for moksha from Lord Vishnu only. I wanna go to Vaikuntha. That's why I am doing fasts of Vishnu, Mata lakshmi and Hanuman because their devotion will make us reach to Vainkunth. But in my dream, destination was set to Lord Shiva for moksha!! Why? I am not getting this at all..

As for additional info, Last night I was so filled with fear and depression regarding my future that I started crying and asked from Lord Vishnu what will happen to me, means what will be my future. I am not seeing any good happening in my future. I also asked while crying that what else shud I do to reach to you (since I was doing fasts to get moksha but I have feeling like only fasts won't be enough to attain moksha in single life so I was determine to do more than fasts also to get moksha). If there is any other fasts which I need to do (apart from tuesday, Ekadashi, SatyaNarayan and Vaibhav Lakshmi's fast which I am doing already) then I can do that also or any other thing apart from fasts that I shud do in order to reach to you, I will do that too... Tell me what shud I do. Later I calmed down and fell asleep. And then had this dream which I mentioned.

Here points whose answer I am trying to find.
1) Why my end destination of moksha was set to shiva in dream (since in dream I had to reach Shiva to get moksha).
2)Why Mata Lakshmi tried to stop me from walking on that that path? Does she had any different plan for me or what?

Please help me to get to know the meaning of this dream and share your valuable knowledge.

Comment: Guiding you to begin your spiritual journey, if you are yet to begin.

Comment: Jury may declare this personal opinion.

Comment: It was just a dream. Your own latent desires were being projected. God if an idea or thought is a product of mind. And that which is product of mind can't know the immeasurable.

Comment: @Rohit. _"Your own latent desires were being projected"_ If this is the case then what Lord Shiva doing in my dream. I am not devotee of Lord Shiva. I don't even think about Lord Shiva. I focus Always on Hanuman, Vishnu and Mata Lakshmi only because their devotion leads us to Vaikunth where I wanna go. So involvement of Lord Shiva is rejecting your theory (as per my sense) :)

Comment: Yeah. @Rohit is right. Dream analysis is off- topic for the site. It comes under personal advice or opinion based. It's in the tag excerpt also. Dream tag is for general questions about dreams. Specific dreams are off topic. There has been meta discussion about it too.https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/262/5212

Comment: You're not aware of your day to day desires & thoughts. Are you? If you were aware, you would know whether you thought about him. As a note, A religious mind is a mind which is more and more factual; less and less assuming.

Comment: @sarvabhouma But our scriptures also says a lot about hidden meaning of dreams. This is the reason I asked here. And also your linked post is just showing personal opinion. As per site rule it is not off-topic to ask question about dream since our scriptures also talks about dream.

Comment: May be not. They talk about dreams generally but not about my dreams I get daily. There can be infinite questions like these. That is the reason we allow general questions about dreams and not dream analysis for person to person because there can be many dreams daily. You have to understand it on your own because you know it very well. Others will only speculate and give opinions. I shown you site rule which shows it's off topic. Some are still off topic even if ask about scriptures too like advice , science.

Comment: @sarvabhouma _"They talk about dreams generally but not what my dreams I get daily"_  Scriptures can't describe every aspects of dream because aspects are endless. But a wise person who has basic understanding of dream concept from scriptures, he can understand those hints of dreams also which is not present in scriptures with help of his experience, wisdom and knowledge. I was hoping to find that person here. And whatever answer that person will give that answer can't be called off-topic coz his answer will be derived from Scriptures.

Comment: Lord Shiva is the lord of destruction, death and in order to attain moksha you have to die first, you can't attain moksha while you are alive, hence the ultimate destination in your dream was Lord Shiva!

Comment: This is 50% Maya and 50% truth.  This could be a projection of mind or really Lord is giving you message via dreams.  Just relate the path which you walked in dream and how you are leading your life. That dream could be symbolic representation of the path you had taken and decisions in life.

Comment: And secondly only an enlightened guru can tell about your dreams. Not us. And moreover,  from where this dream came, there lies the answer too! We can't give you correct answer because we're not still eligible!

Comment: Lord Shiva is brother-in-law of Lord Vishnu. Why discriminate? The trimurthis are equal. Akshay has put his words correctly.  The answer for the  dream question cannot be found from any puranas. It is a personal advice seeking which is off-topic.

Comment: It's not about the source of answers which decides question is on topic. It's question itself. It is personal advice and not in our scope . There are can be 1k questions asking dream interpretations. If you want to ask use [chat]  . It's fine to ask on chat.